# OS X Mavericks upgrade - disk/partition failure

Tags: hard-drive, upgrade, macos

I'm on OS X Lion on my Mac, I have downloaded OS X Mavericks and executed the upgrade.

My Mac restarted and executed the upgrade process, but after a few minutes the update stopped because my OS disk partition "My Macintosh HD" is corrupted. So I tried to check and fix the disk using `Disk Utility` but with no luck.

Can I stop the upgrade process and execute my current OS X Lion again, then copy my files, and make a clean new setup? I can't find any way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried some solutions, but I can't find any secure way to stop the update setup without delete the Mac partition.

The only working solution was to make a clean install.

So:

- I saved much data possible using a bootcamp Win 7 working partition
- then I have restored my last, but old, version (1 years ago!!) on my machine from Time Machine
- from the restoed machine I have downloaded Mavericks, and make a bootable USB setup key
- last I reset the Mac partition and start the setup for a clean install

Now it's working fine, and fortunately, I haven't lost anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had this and I found that I had to have `Disk Utility` repair both the `disk` (top level in the tree) and the `partition` (second level).