# Mac OS X Mavericks fails with disk corruption error

Tags: macos, hard-drive, install

I have a similar problem described by the question posted to this forum labelled "[OS X Mavericks upgrade - disk/partition failure](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106735/os-x-mavericks-upgrade-disk-partition-failure)".  I, however, didn't stop the installation process.  Instead, I continued with the option of later recovering/restoring the files from the Time Machine, believing that all data on my hard disk would be wiped out.

Mac OS X Mavericks was successfully installed, and all files/programs seems to be intact.  What did I do right?  In the case where there was a disk corruption, how could I determine,

1) which files were corrupted?
2) whether or not a log file was generated outlining the corrupt sectors/allocation units?

Also, how would I go about using Time Machine to restore the corrupt files (if any), as I have not done this before?

Any advice/suggestions would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

I suppose my question is whether or not the installation process did, indeed, fix the corruption.  If so, where would I find the 'lost+found' folder (that is, if one exists)?

Comment: Did the Installer make a Folder called incompatible Software? Also check if the 2 invisible partitions were installed (EFI and the Restore)

Comment: @Buscar웃 - Yes, there is a folder called 'Incompatible Software' in the root directory.  It contains three copies of Flip4Mac, which I downloaded a couple of years ago.  Also, there are two hidden partitions that contain EFI and Restore.  I found them using R-Studio, which I purchased last year.  Was not sure how to find the hidden partitions using other (recommended) methods....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are good to go.

During the install it run in to a problem of incompatible software, but once that was out of the way the installer finished the job.

If you want to verify your install, run cmd-r and the restore (online) function. That might take a while so it is your choice to do or not.

The second question:

Enable the Debug in Disk Utility, that will allow you to see the hidden partitions. It is very well hidden, because Apple does not trust us been able to handle our property.

Enter the following command at the Terminal prompt:

```
defaults write com.apple.DiskUtility DUDebugMenuEnabled 1
```

Comment: Thanks Buscar, I might try the cmd-r and restore (online) function tomorrow when I have more time.  As for enabling the Debug under Disk Utility, I might give that a skip since this is a production laptop (i.e. I use it for work), and I don't want to do anything that would cause it to explode.... ;)

Comment: Good decision, you do not want the Hidden partitions exposed. However, you can tun on the debug for your self, then when done turn it off. (0) instead of (1)

Comment: Thanks for your support Buscar!  Will let you know if I have any problems.  Have a good weekend.  Signing off now....

Answer (score 0):

If you are feeling adventuresome, you could try forcing a re-write of the GPT.  I remember way back when it was de rigeur for solving a disk problem.

You need to enter Disk Utility and go to the Partition tab. Reduce the size of the disk a little. Click on "Apply" and let it finish.  Then you can expand it again to the original size and "apply" again.  This only serves to make it do the re-write.

[image]

No guarantee this will solve anything!

Comment: George - Appreciate the feedback, however, this does not answer my question completely.  I suppose my question is whether or not the installation process did resolve the corruption on the disk drive.  If so, where would I find a lost+found folder (if any)?